# Sales & Service Cloud Consultant Maintenance Exams

Tags: release-exam

I have been giving ADM 201 maintenance Exams since 2011. In 2015 Nov I cleared my Sales Cloud Exam and in Jan 2016 I cleared my Service Cloud Exam. But whenever I click on the Consultant Exam link there are no Exams to register, where as the Admin always has option to register for the maintenance Exam. I have'nt given any maintenance Exam since the time I have cleared Sales & Service Cloud. I am scared Iam not looking in the right place for Sales & service Cloud maintenance exam.
Please Help. I don't want to loose my Certifications!!

Answer (score 2):

The Sales Cloud and Service Cloud certifications only require the ADM Maintenance Exam to be passed to maintain their currency.

[Knowledge Base Article](http://certification.force.com/pkb/articles/Public_KB/Maintaining-Your-Salesforce-Credential/?q=release%20exam&l=en_US&fs=Search&pn=1)

> Salesforce Certified Administrator – Release Exam
>
> - Salesforce Certified Administrator
> - Salesforce Certified Advanced Administrator
> - Salesforce Certified Service Cloud Consultant
> - Salesforce Certified Sales Cloud Consultant

Comment: Thanks a tonne Dave.  Just wondering out aloud why there is a separate section called  "Cloud Consultants Exam", which adds to the confusion. Always thought I'd have to click on "Administration Exam" to register for ADM 201 maintenance and "Consultant Exams" to register for Sales & Service Cloud maintenance..Thank you for your prompt answer. Appreciate it.

Comment: Sushma -glad I could make it clearer. Please click the accept answer to drop this question out of the unanswered queue here.